# Update .jpg to .png in particular column

Tags: sql, replace

I have an SQL table called `buzzinga_menulist` with an `image` column containing values like:

```
x1.jpg
x2.jpg
x3.jpg
x4.jpg
```

How do I update all values ending with `.jpg` suffixes to have `.png` suffixes instead? I've tried the following but it gives me a syntax error.

```
UPDATE buzzinga_menulist
SET image = replace(*, '.png', '.jpg')
WHERE image = '.jpg';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
UPDATE `buzzinga_menulist`
SET `image` = REPLACE(`image`, '.jpg', '.png');
```